# dinamically change value by use setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to change name by using increment function, that will change name every 300 msec

```
class NumberModel {
    constructor () {
        this.color = 'red';
    }
    increment () {
    const colors = ['orange', 'red', 'green', 'blue'];
    setInterval(()=>{this.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    console.log(this.color)},300);
```

but when i create object and applied function increment and run this code nothing happens

Comment: What is not working exactly? What should be happening that is not? Can we have your code that does not have a syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

It's working at my end:

```
class NumberModel {
    constructor () {
        this.color = 'red';
    }
    increment () {
    const colors = ['orange', 'red', 'green', 'blue'];
    setInterval(()=>{this.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    console.log(this.color)},300);
    }
}
```

then use it like:

```
var nm = new NumberModel();
nm.increment();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issues with the code.

Take a look at the following snippet.

```js
class NumberModel {
  constructor() {
    this.color = 'red';
  }

  increment() {
    const colors = ['orange', 'red', 'green', 'blue'];

    setInterval(() => {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)
      this.color = colors[randomIndex];
      console.log(this.color)
    }, 300);
  }
}

const numberModel = new NumberModel()

numberModel.increment();
```

Comment: Thanks, i found my mistake.... forgot put () when apply function

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you misspell somewhere. 
check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mgq54z?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the goal is for every 0.3 seconds to select a random color from the array and prints it in the console.

```
class NumberModel {

    constructor() {
      this.color = 'red';
    }

    increment() {
      const colors = ['orange', 'red', 'green', 'blue'];

      setInterval(() => {
        this.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

        console.log(this.color)

      }, 300);

    }
  }


  const numberModelOne = new NumberModel 
  numberModelOne.increment() //prints every 0.3 eternally random color from the array
```

In my case, it's working well.

But you missed closing some curly brackets. Add } x 2 at the end.